# Is there a way to get a buggy package to work on debian stretch?

Tags: debian, bugs, isc-dhcpd

I need to install `isc-dhcp-server` on debian stretch, but the package cannot be installed correctly.

`apt-listbugs list isc-dhcp-server`:

```
 #867362 - isc-dhcp-server: DHCP server does not start after upgrade to Stretch
```

After installing the package

```
# systemctl status isc-dhcp-server

● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-10-05 11:47:47 UTC; 2min 52s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5416 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

oct. 05 11:47:45 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5416]: Launching both IPv4 and IPv6 servers (please configure INTERFACES in /etc/default/isc
oct. 05 11:47:45 stretch dhcpd[5427]: irs_resconf_load failed: 59.
oct. 05 11:47:45 stretch dhcpd[5427]: Unable to set resolver from resolv.conf; startup continuing but DDNS support may be affected
oct. 05 11:47:45 stretch dhcpd[5427]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5416]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5416]:  failed!
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Installing the package [from source](https://www.isc.org/downloads/) (4.3.6 version) cannot solve the problem, Is there a way to install `isc-dhcp-server` on debian stretch?

`journalctl | grep isc-dhcp-server`:

```
oct. 05 11:45:09 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5288]: Launching both IPv4 and IPv6 servers (please configure INTERFACES in /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server if you only want one or the other).
oct. 05 11:45:12 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5288]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
oct. 05 11:45:12 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5288]:  failed!
oct. 05 11:45:12 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
oct. 05 11:45:11 stretch audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=isc-dhcp-server comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
oct. 05 11:45:12 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
oct. 05 11:45:12 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct. 05 11:47:45 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5416]: Launching both IPv4 and IPv6 servers (please configure INTERFACES in /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server if you only want one or the other).
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5416]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch isc-dhcp-server[5416]:  failed!
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=isc-dhcp-server comm="systemd" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
oct. 05 11:47:47 stretch systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`systemctl list-units --state=failed` :

```
  UNIT                    LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                                        
● dnsmasq.service         loaded failed failed dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
● isc-dhcp-server.service loaded failed failed LSB: DHCP server
```

Comment: If you are indeed running into the same bug, `rm /var/run/dhcpd.pid` should fix the problem; but given your systemd logs, there might be something else going on.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thank you , i have update the question . The `dhcpd.pid` doesn't exist .

Comment: I am using it in Stretch *without* systemd and it works well.

Comment: FWIW, I'm no fan of `systemd`, but it also seems unlikely to be the problem. I recommend figuring out what is wrong with your setup and fixing it, rather than working around it by moving away from `systemd`. Sometimes running services by hand helps in debugging them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using the official ISC DHCPd Debian packages in Stretch *without* systemd, and been using it in Debian and upgrading that particular DHCP cluster since Debian 6 without many hitches.

As for Stretch, I have been using isc-dhcp on it for over a year, *I think*, since I migrated earlier to take advantage of new versions, instead of assembling a deb of my own. (I had some reasons related to Windows DHCP clients)

As normally those kind of services should be alone in a machine, I suggest making an exception and have a Debian server with the sysV init utilities.

For that, you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install  sysvinit-core sysvinit
```